# (iOS) Accelerometer Graph (convert g-force to +/- 128) granularity

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, accelerometer

I am using this [Accelerometer graph](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007410-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple and trying to convert their G-force code to calculate **+/- 128**.

The following image shows that the **x**, **y**, **z** values in the labels do not match the output on the graph: *(Note that `addX:y:z` values are what is shown in the labels above the graph)*

[image]

### ViewController

The **x, y, z** values are received from a bluetooth peripheral, then converted using:

```
// Updates LABELS
- (void)didReceiveRawAcceleromaterDataWithX:(NSInteger)x Y:(NSInteger)y Z:(NSInteger)z
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _labelAccel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x:%li  y:%li  z:%li", (long)x, (long)y, (long)z];
    });
}

// Updates GRAPHS
- (void)didReceiveAcceleromaterDataWithX:(NSInteger)x Y:(NSInteger)y Z:(NSInteger)z
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        float xx = ((float)x) / 8192;
        float yy = ((float)y) / 8192;
        float zz = ((float)z) / 8192;

        [_xGraph addX:xx y:0 z:0];
        [_yGraph addX:0 y:yy z:0];
        [_zGraph addX:0 y:0 z:zz];

    });
}
```

### GraphView

```
- (BOOL)addX:(UIAccelerationValue)x y:(UIAccelerationValue)y z:(UIAccelerationValue)z
{
    // If this segment is not full, then we add a new acceleration value to the history.
    if (index > 0)
    {
        // First decrement, both to get to a zero-based index and to flag one fewer position left
        --index;
        xhistory[index] = x;
        yhistory[index] = y;
        zhistory[index] = z;
        // And inform Core Animation to redraw the layer.
        [layer setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    // And return if we are now full or not (really just avoids needing to call isFull after adding a value).
    return index == 0;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)l inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Fill in the background
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, kUIColorLightGray(1.f).CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, layer.bounds);

    // Draw the grid lines
    DrawGridlines(context, 0.0, 32.0);

    // Draw the graph
    CGPoint lines[64];
    int i;

    float _granularity = 16.f; // 16
    NSInteger _granualCount = 32; // 32

    // X
    for (i = 0; i < _granualCount; ++i)
    {
        lines[i*2].x = i;
        lines[i*2+1].x = i + 1;

        lines[i*2].y = xhistory[i] * _granularity;
        lines[i*2+1].y = xhistory[i+1] * _granularity;
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _xColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, lines, 64);

    // Y
    for (i = 0; i < _granualCount; ++i)
    {
        lines[i*2].y = yhistory[i] * _granularity;
        lines[i*2+1].y = yhistory[i+1] * _granularity;
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _yColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, lines, 64);

    // Z
    for (i = 0; i < _granualCount; ++i)
    {
        lines[i*2].y = zhistory[i] * _granularity;
        lines[i*2+1].y = zhistory[i+1] * _granularity;
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _zColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeLineSegments(context, lines, 64);
}
```

How can I calculate the above code to show the correct accelerometer values on the graph with precision?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how the labels are created and updated.

Comment: @robmayoff updated my question.

Comment: I don't see any code that updates “x:-2 y:-54 z:32” labels.

Comment: are you sure you haven't just got your labels wired up to the wrong values? looks as if your problem _may_ be that xLabel is showing yValue, yLabel is showing zValue and zLabel is showing xValue.

Comment: The labels are connected correctly. The **issue** has to do with converting the +/- 128 float values (xx, yy, zz) to work with the graph (which seems to be calculating g-force, though I have changed the numbers from ( +/- 3 ). If I change `float _granularity = 16.f` to something like **4.f**, the lines do not jump as much, and do not match the expectations; though is somewhat more of what I am looking for.

Comment: could you please provide code that call `didReceiveRawAcceleromaterDataWithX...` & `didReceiveAcceleromaterDataWithX...` ?

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an aswer not a comment, because I have not enough reputation, but what I'll write might be enough to send you in the right direction, that it even may count as an answer...

Your question still doesn't include what is really important. I assume the calculation of the xx/yy/zz is no problem. Although I have no idea what the 8192 is supposed to mean.

I guess the preblem is in the part where you map your values to pixel coordinates...
the lines[] contains your values in a range of 1/8192th of the values in the label. so your x value of -2 should be at a pixel position of -0.0000something, so slightly(far less than 1 Pixel) above the view... Because you see the line a lot further down there must be some translation in place (not shown in your code)

The second part that is important but not shown is DrawGridlines. Probably in there is a different approach to map the values to pixel-coordinates...

Use the debugger to check what pixel-coordinates you get when draw your +127-line and what you get if you insert the value of +127 in your history-array

And some Ideas for improvements when reading your code:
1.)Put the graph in it's own class that draws one graph(and has only one history. Somehow you seem to have that partially already (otherwise I cannot figure out your _xGraph/_yGraph/_zGraph) But on the other hand you draw all 3 values in one drawLayer??? Currently you seem to have 3*3 history buffers of which 3*2 are filled with zeros...
2.) use one place where you do the calculation of Y that you use both for drawing the grid and drawing the lines...
3.) use  CGContextMoveToPoint(); + CGContextAddLineToPoint(); instead of copying into lines[] with these ugly 2*i+1 indecies...